# rails 3 not pluralizing table name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pluralize

I am trying to migrate from rails 2 to rails 3.

I am facing a strange problem.

The whole of application doesn't seem to pluralize the table names.

> Mysql::Error: Table 'r_database.country_data' doesn't exist:

But my table has country_datas as the name.

App was working perfectly in rails 2.

Comment: I have another rails 3 app. that works fine.. so nothing to do with my OS or rails configuration

Comment: can you put your Gemfile in here? And can you put the backtrace of the error?

Comment: @Michael Koper .  I got the answer from Michael Johnston

Answer (score 7, accepted):

rails 3 recognizes that (in english) data is already plural. you'll have to either add a custom inflection in initializers, or use set_table_name "country_datas" in your model.

Comment: I think indeed set_table_name is the right thing to do here. custom inflections could be bad for other translations.

Comment: Yes.. I would rather run a migration to rename the table itself.. :)

Comment: @Gaurav: even though I am a native english speaker, I will name a variable that is a collection xxxx_datas rather than xxxx_data. Too confusing otherwise